# Android Studio 4.0 Gradle build not finished

Tags: android, gradle, studio

He probado con todas las soluciones que dan en stackoverflow, pero nada, he instalado y desinstalado todas las versiones, ahora con la 4.0, la instalacion todo bien, borro las carpetas .gradle .android las carpetas de instalacion, he probado a crear el archivo gradle.properties y poner:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

La conexion a internet es correcta, esto me pasa en el portatil, en el sobremesa, con la misma configuracion (hasta los mismos programas) no tengo ningun problema.

Abro un proyecto nuevo, uno existente, pero nada, he probado a borrar la cache se tira horas y horas con el Gradle sync started y obviamente no puedo hacer nada.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Porqué borras la carpeta .gradle?

Comment: Vi en un hilo que borraban todo, pues antes de instalar el ide, pues la borro por si hay habia alguna version corrupta

Comment: Si vuelves a instalar Android studio tampoco funciona? Si ya instalas no deberías borrar ninguna carpeta. Con qué version de Android Studio creaste tu proyecto? Creo que hay conflictos con la version 4.0 si abres proyectos creados menores a esa version.

Comment: Cuando hago una instalación limpia, la última con android 4.0 creo un proyecto nuevo y nada, Gradley sync started...... horas y horas. Las carpetas que borro son al desinstalar, cuando instalo el ide, no borro nada

Comment: Son muchas las causas de este problema, deberías revisar si tu proyecto no tiene errores en sus archivos y recursos.

Comment: No es con un proyecto en particular, es con todos, incluso cuando creo uno nuevo, limpio sin nada de codigo, solo el hola mundo y nada.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado: Aunque en el firewall de windows 10 tenia los permisos para acceder a la red y el test de conexion era correcto, el firewall no le daba acceso, he instalado el firewall TinyWall y ahora todo bien.
Mucho cuidado con el firewall de windows 10